# StackExchange API /sites/ does not return all the sites

Tags: support, api-v2, sites

I am working on one application that produces timeline of user on every site of StackExchange.. We have some users on Sharepoint.stackexchange.com..

Since I want list of all the sites, I am trying to get it using API 2.2

`2.2/sites/`

as shown here.. But it is getting only partial sites. It is missing sites like Beer.stackexchange, sharepoint.stackexchange..

How do I retrieve them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass in a sufficiently large `pagesize` value, per [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites):

> The pagesize parameter for this method is unbounded, in acknowledgement that for many applications repeatedly fetching from /sites would complicate start-up tasks needlessly.

Otherwise you'll only get 30 results, the default value for `pagesize`. Alternatively, you can [page the results](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), but setting a large page size (e.g. 10000) is probably easier in this case.

As an aside, it'd probably be nice if the `pagesize` parameter allowed a special `all` value for this case, so you didn't have to use a magic number, but.

Comment: It would be really nice if a few other endpoints had unbounded pagesizes (like getting a users associated accounts, which is limited to the number if sites just like /sites is)